# How to exclude multiple files from phpunit using the xml config?

Tags: php, phpunit

I've got the following in my xml file, but it's not skipping the second file:

```
<testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
            <exclude>./app/tests/unit/1.php</exclude>
            <exclude>./app/tests/unit/2.php</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use the [phpunit group annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) for tagging the classes/methods  and mark that group as excluded from the main test suite.
You can read [this article](http://mikenaberezny.com/2007/09/04/better-phpunit-group-annotations/) as further reference.

As example, you can do as follow in your test class:

```
class 1 extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @group excludeMe
     */
    public function testSomething()
    {
    }

    public function testSomethingElseDoNotExclude()
    {
    }

 ...

}
```

And add your group as excluded in the `phpunit.xml` files, as example:

```
<phpunit 
 ....
>
   ....
    <groups>
        <exclude>
            <group>excludeMe</group>
        </exclude>
    </groups>
</phpunit>
```

More info about the groups in the [xml annotation reference](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) and search for `<groups>`

Hope this help